Top Tags requiring a tag wiki
Tag wikis give a short overview detailing what kind of questions a tag collects. Tag wiki excerpts are shown on hover, and even more importantly, when users tag a question post. 
There are currently 392 tags without even a tag excerpt.
If you have sufficient reputation, please contribute in tags that you have upvotes for. Even before you can edit tags yourself, you can submit suggested edits!
Please write original texts, and don’t copy from other sites.
Let’s start by taking on the top fifty!

The following are the top fifty tags without an excerpt

Whenever you add a tag wiki, please remove the corresponding tag from the list here.
  Please use the dictionary method for the excerpt: Don’t repeat the name of the tag, unless the tag abbreviates it.


server (77)
php (72)
services (60)
python (48)
sending (46)
error (45)
database (43)
verification (42)
offline (42)
address-generation (41)
merchants (39)
contracts (37)
proof-of-stake (36)
market (36)
passphrase (35)
receiving (32)
stratum (32)
peers (31)
money (31)
multi-sig (30)
connection (29)
hacking (29)
import (29)
message (29)
tor (29)
theory (29)
regtest (28)
theft (27)
payment-processors (27)
lost-bitcoins (27)
nonce (26)
trade (26)
performance (26)
storage (26)
conversion (24)
p2sh (24)

Done

raw-transaction (95)
hash (61)
proof-of-work (53)
coldstorage (53)
multi-sig-addresses (48)
android (48)
unconfirmed-transactions (47)
hashpower (45)
privacy (44)
asicminer (42)
transaction-malleability (42)
transaction-verification (39)
taxes (33)
compiling (26)

